# Getting data from Facebook Graph API Explorer

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When I'm try to get all the comments on a certain public post on Facebook with the following GET request it only shows me a limited number of comments.

```
<post-id>/comments
```

I tried changing the limit field as following but what is the GET request I should use to get all the comments on that post?

Comment: Can you give api url to try it out!

Comment: Grpah Explorer - developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer 
Graph API doc : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

Comment: I mean fb comment api which you are trying to GET. not docs

Comment: This is the API explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer.
The API is here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

Comment: I am asking for url which your are using to get comments, like fb.com/<post-id>..... Not docs. I am sure you wont get even a single response if you hit the url you've given

Comment: This is the GET request. Sorry I was confused http://graph.facebook.com/21785951839_10155597656246840/comments

Comment: Paging is what you are looking for. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging

Comment: Oh! I'll refer that and give a try, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/comments?limit=500

the max value of limit is 500